# Difficulty defining RxJS and Stomp operators

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rxjs, stomp

I'm stuck on a problem, I can't set RxJS to update the UI in real time as messages are sent to websocket. The connection is working and messages are being sent to the socket.

```
private connectedUserMessages$: Subject<ChatMessage> = new Subject();   

onConnected(nickname: string, fullname: string): any {
this.stompClient.subscribe(
  `/user/${nickname}/queue/messages`,
  (payload: any) => {
    const newMessage = JSON.parse(payload.body);
    this.connectedUserMessages$.next(newMessage);
  }
);
```

Observables:

```
  getUserMessages(
    senderId: string,
    recipientId: string
  ): Observable<ChatMessage[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<ChatMessage[]>(
      `${this.messagesUrl}/${senderId}/${recipientId}`
    );
  } 

     getConnectedUserMessages(): Observable<ChatMessage> {
        return this.connectedUserMessages$.asObservable();
      }
```

In the component I concatenate the old messages from the database with the new ones sent with the "map" and manipulate the service in the constructor:

```
messages$: Observable<ChatMessage[]> = EMPTY;
constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.messageService.getConnectedUserMessages().subscribe(message => {
      console.log("New message from socket");
      console.log({ message });
      this.addMessageIfNotExists(message);
    });
    this.messages$.subscribe();    
  }
```

This is the rest of the logic for adding a message to the interface:

```
 selectUser(selectedUser: User) {
    this.selectedUserId = selectedUser.nickName;
    this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    this.messages$ = concat(this.messageService.getUserMessages(this.connectedUser!.nickName, selectedUser.nickName),
      this.messageService.getConnectedUserMessages()
    ).pipe(
      scan((messages: ChatMessage[], newMessage) => {
        console.log("scan");
        console.log([messages]);
        console.log({ newMessage });
        if (Array.isArray(newMessage)) {
          return [...messages, ...newMessage];
        } else {
          return [...messages, newMessage];
        }
      }, []),
      map((messages) =>
        messages.sort(
          (a, b) =>
            new Date(a.timestamp ?? new Date()).getTime() -
            new Date(b.timestamp ?? new Date()).getTime()
        )
      )
    );
  }

  addMessageIfNotExists(message: ChatMessage) {
    this.messages$ = this.messages$.pipe(
      map((messages) => {
        const messageExists = messages.some((msg) => msg.id === message.id);
        return messageExists ? messages : [...messages, message];
      }),
      map((messages) =>
        messages.sort(
          (a, b) =>
            new Date(a.timestamp ?? new Date()).getTime() -
            new Date(b.timestamp ?? new Date()).getTime()
        )
      )
    );
  }

  sendMessage() {
    if (this.connectedUser && this.selectedUserId && this.message) {
      const uniqueMessageId = Date.now().toString();
      this.messageService.sendMessage(
        this.connectedUser.nickName,
        this.selectedUserId,
        this.message,
        uniqueMessageId
      );
      const newMessage: ChatMessage = {
        id: uniqueMessageId,
        chat: undefined,
        senderId: this.connectedUser.nickName,
        recipientId: this.selectedUserId,
        content: this.message,
        timestamp: new Date(),
      };
      this.addMessageIfNotExists(newMessage);
      this.message = '';
    }
  }
```

```
<div id="chat-messages" #chatMessages>
        <ng-container *ngIf="(messages$ | async) as messages">
          <div *ngFor="let receivedMessage of messages; let i = index" class="message">
            <div *ngIf="isFirstMessageOfDay(receivedMessage, i, messages)" class="date-marker">
              {{ receivedMessage.timestamp | date : "EEEE, d 'de' MMMM 'de' y" : "+0000" : "pt" }}
            </div>
            <div class="message-header" [ngClass]="
                receivedMessage.senderId === connectedUser.nickName ? 'sender-header': 'receiver-header' ">
              <span>{{ getUserFullName(receivedMessage.senderId) }} às&nbsp;</span>
              <span>{{ receivedMessage.timestamp | date : "HH:mm" }}</span>
            </div>
            <p [ngClass]="
                receivedMessage.senderId === connectedUser.nickName ? 'sender' : 'receiver'">
              {{ receivedMessage.content }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
```

Where is my error in updating the UI in real time as messages arrive in the Observable

Comment: Please include your template code. That's likely where the issue is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention, I made an edit and added the template.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. Replacing the observable used in the template (`this.messages$ = ...`) during  the lifetime of the component will break the binding. Try to find a way to set `messages$` once and let it change over time in response other events.
2. You should not need to call `.subscribe()` on an observable in your component code if you are also using it in a template binding (`... | async`). The async pipe already subscribes to the observable for you, and will unsubscribe when your component is destroyed. Adding a `.subscribe()` will cause a memory leak if you don't manually unsubscribe on destroy.